# How to copy a folder from docker to other folder?

Tags: docker, copy, directory

`RUN cp /data/ /data/db`, this command does not copy the files in `/data` to `/data/db`.

Is there an alternate way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends where `/data` is for you: already in the image, or on your host disk.

A [`Dockerfile RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/builder/#run) command execute any commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results.

That means `/data` is the one found in the image as built so far.
Not the `/data` on your disk.

If you want to copy from your disk to the image `/data/db` folder, you would need to use [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/builder/#copy) or [`ADD`](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/builder/#add).

At runtime, when you had an existing running container, you could also use [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) to copy from or to a container.